# pip install pattern getting SyntaxError : Missing parentheses in call to 'print'

Tags: pip, python-3.6

I am using Python-3.6 and trying to install "pattern" module for doing Natural Language Processing.

But while I am trying to install it using pip in my windows powershell, I am getting the below error :

> SyntaxError : Missing parentheses in call to 'print'

The In-Detail error screenshot is attached for reference.
[image]
Anybody have any thoughts on how to resolve the same ?

Comment: No support for python 3

Comment: https://github.com/clips/pattern#installation says that the released version only support 2.x. Only the development version supports python 3.

Comment: Hi @mwweb and @omajid I noticed both of them but as per this page https://github.com/clips/pattern/commit/ac0011bc921e8d868c11f85851a03a03ef1cab3c, it says as below  "Pattern supports Python 2.7 and Python 3.6+. The Python 3 version is currently **only** available on the `development` branch. To install Pattern so that it is available in all your scripts, unzip the download and from the command line do:
 ```bash
 cd pattern-2.6
 python setup.py install"

So it does mean that we can install and use this in Python-3.6 also right ?

Comment: I tried to execute the "python setup.py install" command after going in to the Patter-2.6 folder location in both Powershell and Windows cmd prompt but got the error as 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command. So any idea on how to install it manually ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Install `development` branch directly from Github:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/clips/pattern@development#egg=pattern
```

Comment: It was throwing error. Later I identified that instead of '?', '#' should be mentioned. It worked like a charm. Thank you so much

Comment: Fixed. Tnx for reminding. I always fail at that sign. :-)

Comment: But can you please explain the usage of #egg=pattern. I thought it was a comment. Sorry I am new to this. Is it like installing only the pattern module from a list of other modules ?

Comment: It's not a comment, it's a part of URL called `hash`. `pip` uses `hash` to know the name of the package being installed. See the docs at https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#vcs-support

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation